# SVG draw animation single line left to right

Tags: html, svg

I need to make this SVG draw from left to right, I made the SVG in photoshop using paths of 1px and then converted the paths to shapes but the paths aren't connected so the animation starts at all points instead of a long continuous path.

Is there a quick way to connect these paths in HTML? or do I have to merge them all together in photoshop?

Any help would be appreciated.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1430" height="846" viewBox="0 0 1430 846">
  <metadata><?xpacket begin="﻿" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?>
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="Adobe XMP Core 5.6-c138 79.159824, 2016/09/14-01:09:01        ">
   <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
      <rdf:Description rdf:about=""/>
   </rdf:RDF>
</x:xmpmeta>
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                           
<?xpacket end="w"?></metadata>
<defs>
    <style>
      svg {
  max-width: 95%;
  max-height: 95%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
svg path {
  fill-opacity: 0;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 1;
  stroke-dasharray: 870;
  stroke-dashoffset: 870;
  animation: draw 10s infinite linear;
}
@keyframes draw {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
    </style>
  </defs>
  <path class="cls-1" d="M97,801H96V744h1v57Zm-0.6-56.7L95.6,743.7l10-13,0.792,0.61ZM106,731h-1V721h1v10Zm-0.422,1.268,0.844-.536,7,11-0.844.536ZM112,743h1v6h-1v-6Zm0.61,6.312,0.78-.624,4,5-0.78.624ZM117,754v-1h8v1h-8Zm8,0h-1V705h1v49Zm0.481-48.865-0.962-.27,7-25,0.962,0.27ZM132,680h-1V660h1v20Zm-1.568-20.252-0.864.5-7-12,0.864-.5Zm-7.062-11.412-0.74-.672,10-11,0.74,0.672ZM133,637h-1V583h1v54Zm-1.588-53.717-0.824-.566,11-16,0.824,0.566Zm10.214-15.951,0.748-.664,8,9-0.748.664ZM150,576v-1h32v1H150Zm31.664-.63,0.672-.74,11,10-0.672.74ZM192,585h1v56h-1V585Zm2,56v-1h27v1H194Zm12-1h-1V601h1v39Zm15,1h-1V585h1v56Zm-0.646-55.646-0.708-.708,9-9,0.708,0.708ZM230,576v-1h32v1H230Zm32.354-.646-0.708-.708,7-7,0.708,0.708Zm6.292-8,0.708-.708,10,10-0.708.708ZM278,576h1v60h-1V576Zm-0.369,60.338,0.738-.676,11,12-0.738.676ZM288.6,647.706l0.808,0.588-8,11-0.808-.588ZM280.5,659.055l0.994-.11,4,36-0.994.11Zm4.027,36.116,0.94-.342,4,11-0.94.342ZM288,706h1v48h-1V706Zm1.487,0.112-0.974-.224,3-13,0.974,0.224ZM292,693h-1V666h1v27Zm0.217-26.549-0.434-.9,27-13,0.434,0.9Zm26.62-12.978,0.326-.946,32,11-0.326.946ZM350,664h1v51h-1V664Zm1,51v-1h11v1H351Zm11,0h-1V629h1v86Zm-0.929-85.5-0.142-.99,7-1,0.142,0.99Zm6.619-1.1,0.62-.784,19,15-0.62.784ZM386,643h1v49h-1V643Zm1,49v-1h7v1h-7Zm6.743,0.429,0.514-.858,10,6-0.514.858ZM403,698h1v35h-1V698Zm1.7,35.4,0.6-.8,8,6-0.6.8Zm8,6,0.6-.8,4,3-0.6.8ZM418,742h1v13h-1V742Zm1,1h-1V674h1v69Zm0.354-68.646-0.708-.708,4-4,0.708,0.708ZM423,670v-1H535v1H423Zm111.688-.61,0.624-.78,5,4-0.624.78Zm4.9,3.319,0.814,0.582-5,7-0.814-.582Zm-4.973,7.616,0.76-.65,6,7-0.76.65Zm5.946,6.427,0.868,0.5-4,7-0.868-.5ZM536,694h1v22h-1V694Zm0.366,15.34-0.732-.68,13-14,0.732,0.68Zm13.087-14.129-0.906-.422,14-30,0.906,0.422ZM563,665h-1V640h1v25Zm-1-25v-1h11v1H562Zm11.312-1.61-0.624-.78,5-4,0.624,0.78Zm5.168-4.249-0.96-.282,23-78,0.96,0.282ZM601,556h-1V543h1v13Zm0.39-13.312-0.78.624-8-10,0.78-.624Zm-8.113-9.272-0.554-.832,15-10,0.554,0.832Zm15.22-10.358-0.994-.116,7-60,0.994,0.116Zm7-60.016-1-.084,4-47,1,0.084Zm4-47.016-1-.052,3-57,1,0.052Zm3-56.994-1-.064,4-63,1,0.064Zm4-62.994-1-.076,4-53,1,0.076Zm3.908-53.329-0.814.582-5-7,0.814-.582Zm-4.933-6.867-0.948.316-3-9,0.948-.316ZM622,227h-1V217h1v10Zm0.5-9.95-1-.1,1-10,1,0.1Zm0.962-9.853-0.92-.394,3-7,0.92,0.394Zm2.947-6.906-0.814-.582,5-7,0.814,0.582Zm4.947-6.937-0.708-.708,7-7,0.708,0.708Zm7-7-0.708-.708,2-2,0.708,0.708ZM640,184h-1V167h1v17Zm0.671,0.376,0.658-.752,8,7-0.658.752Zm7.9,6.889,0.848-.53,5,8-0.848.53Zm4.956,7.911,0.936-.352,3,8-0.936.352Zm2.97,7.869,1-.09,1,11-1,.09Zm1,10.893,0.992,0.124-1,8-0.992-.124Zm-0.978,7.9,0.948,0.316-3,9-0.948-.316ZM653.54,234.8l0.92,0.394-3,7-0.92-.394Zm-4.039,8.229,1-.064,5,77-1,.064Zm5,76.995,1-.054,4,73-1,.054Zm4,73.009,1-.072,2,28-1,.072Zm2,28.008,1-.088,6,68-1,.088Zm6,68.038,0.986-.164,5,30-0.986.164Zm5.168,30.3,0.65-.76,14,12-0.65.76Zm13.878,11.844,0.894-.448,1,2-0.894.448Zm1.073,1.444,0.748,0.664-8,9-0.748-.664ZM678,542h1v11h-1V542Zm0.518,11.133,0.964-.266,21,76-0.964.266Zm21.072,76.154,0.82-.574,7,10-0.82.574ZM707,639v-1h9v1h-9Zm8,0h1v26h-1V639Zm-0.436,27.244,0.872-.488,42,75-0.872.488ZM725.5,761.95l-1,.1-1-10,1-.1Zm-1.013-10.071-0.97.242-2-8,0.97-.242Zm-2.038-8.1-0.894.448-4-8,0.894-.448Zm-4.023-8.041-0.848.53-5-8,0.848-.53Zm-5.008-8.012-0.832.554-6-9,0.832-.554Zm-6.062-9.077-0.708.708-8-8,0.708-.708ZM699.3,710.6l-0.6.8-8-6,0.6-.8Zm-8.032-6.022-0.536.844-11-7,0.536-.844Zm-11.044-7.025-0.448.894-10-5,0.448-.894Zm-10.066-5.027-0.316.948-12-4,0.316-.948ZM658.045,688.5l-0.09,1-11-1,0.09-1ZM647,687v1H634v-1h13Zm-13.071.5,0.142,0.99-14,2-0.142-.99Zm-14.087,2.021,0.316,0.948-12,4-0.316-.948Zm-12.066,4.027,0.448,0.894-10,5-0.448-.894Zm-10.019,5.01,0.486,0.874-9,5-0.486-.874Zm-9.091,5.065,0.668,0.744-10,9-0.668-.744Zm-10.02,9.018,0.708,0.708-9,9-0.708-.708Zm-9.056,9.067,0.82,0.574-7,10-0.82-.574Zm-7.037,10.063,0.894,0.448-5,10-0.894-.448Zm-5.038,10.1,0.97,0.242-3,12-0.97-.242ZM554.5,753.955l1,0.09-1,11-1-.09ZM553.6,765.3l0.8-.6,3,4-0.8.6ZM557,769v-1h12v1H557Zm12-1h-1V753h1v15Zm1-15v-1h21v1H570Zm21.354,0.354-0.708-.708,6-6,0.708,0.708ZM597,747h-1V734h1v13Zm0.3-12.6-0.6-.8,8-6,0.6,0.8Zm7.733-5.9-0.066-1,15-1,0.066,1ZM619,727h1v41h-1V727Zm0.68,41.384,0.64-.768,6,5-0.64.768Zm6.674,4.97-0.708-.708,4-4,0.708,0.708ZM630,768h-1V716h1v52Zm0.291-51.593-0.582-.814,7-5,0.582,0.814ZM637,711v-1h25v1H637Zm24.646-.646,0.708-.708,5,5-0.708.708ZM666,715h1v46h-1V715Zm1,46v-1h58v1H667Zm90-20h-1V716h1v25Zm0.307-24.605-0.614-.79,9-7,0.614,0.79ZM766,709v-1h26v1H766Zm26-1h-1V642h1v66Zm-0.743-65.571-0.514-.858,10-6,0.514,0.858ZM801,636v-1h13v1H801Zm12.68,0.384,0.64-.768,6,5-0.64.768Zm6.632,5.006-0.624-.78,5-4,0.624,0.78ZM825,637h-1V485h1V637Zm-0.571-150.743-0.858-.514,6-10,0.858,0.514ZM830,476h-1V465h1v11Zm0.354-10.646-0.708-.708,14-14,0.708,0.708ZM843,449h1v29h-1V449Zm-0.354,29.354,0.708-.708,6,6-0.708.708ZM850,484v-1h44v1H850Zm43,1h1V694h-1V485Zm0.752,209.434,0.5-.868,7,4-0.5.868ZM901,698v-1h10v1H901Zm10.457,0.2-0.914-.406,4-9,0.914,0.406ZM915,689v-1h4v1h-4Zm3,0h1v19h-1V689Zm2,19v-1h3v1h-3Zm3.39,0.312-0.78-.624,4-5,0.78,0.624ZM927,703h-1V691h1v12Zm0.354-11.646-0.708-.708,6-6,0.708,0.708ZM933,685h-1V671h1v14Zm0.4-13.7-0.8-.6,21-28,0.8,0.6ZM954,643h-1V622h1v21Zm0.468-20.824-0.936-.352,6-16,0.936,0.352Zm5.1-15.928,0.868-.5,8,14-0.868.5ZM967,620h1v22h-1V620Zm0.607,22.309,0.786-.618,11,14-0.786.618ZM979,656v-1h3v1h-3Zm3.5,0.028-1-.056,1-18,1,0.056Zm0.992-17.936-0.982-.184,3-16,0.982,0.184Zm3-15.977-0.974-.23,4-17,0.974,0.23Zm3.966-16.9-0.906-.422,7-15,0.906,0.422ZM997.4,590.3l-0.8-.6,9-12,0.8,0.6Zm8.97-11.962-0.74-.676,11-12,0.74,0.676Zm11-12-0.74-.668,9-10,0.74,0.668ZM1026,557h-1V517h1v40Zm0.42-39.73-0.84-.54,9-14,0.84,0.54Zm8.17-13.979,0.82-.582,10,14-0.82.582ZM1044,517h1v39h-1V517Zm0.63,39.335,0.74-.67,19,21-0.74.67Zm18.94,20.927,0.86-.524,8,13-0.86.524Zm7.97,12.924,0.92-.372,6,15-0.92.372Zm5.98,14.955,0.96-.282,5,17-0.96.282Zm4.99,16.951,0.98-.184,3,16-0.98.184ZM1085,638h1v11h-1V638Zm0.65,13.354,0.7-.708,4,4-0.7.708Zm4.7,4-0.7-.708,13-13,0.7,0.708ZM1103,642h-1V613h1v29Zm0.39-28.688-0.78-.624,4-5,0.78,0.624Zm3.26-4.958,0.7-.708,5,5-0.7.708ZM1111,615h1v15h-1V615Zm0.65,15.354,0.7-.708,4,4-0.7.708ZM1116,634h1v10h-1V634Zm0.61,10.31,0.78-.62,15,19-0.78.62Zm14.91,18.823,0.96-.266,8,29-0.96.266Zm7.98,28.9,1-.072,1,14-1,.072Zm1.17,14.338,0.66-.748,9,8-0.66.748ZM1150,714v-1h9v1h-9Zm8.61,0.312,0.78-.624,4,5-0.78.624ZM1162,719h1v25h-1V719Zm1.35,25.354-0.7-.708,11-11,0.7,0.708ZM1174,733h-1V711h1v22Zm0.05-21.5-0.1-1,10-1,0.1,1Zm9.6-1.144,0.7-.708,11,11-0.7.708ZM1195,721h-1V660h1v61Zm-0.67-60.622-0.66-.756,22-19,0.66,0.756ZM1216,641v-1h10v1h-10Zm9.65,0.354,0.7-.708,4,4-0.7.708ZM1230,645v-1h22v1h-22Zm21,0h1v95h-1V645Zm1,95v-1h12v1h-12Zm12-1h-1v-9h1v9Zm0.35-8.646-0.7-.708,9-9,0.7,0.708ZM1274,721h-1V687h1v34Zm0-34v-1h21v1h-21Zm21.35,0.354-0.7-.708,14-14,0.7,0.708ZM1308,671h1v16h-1V671Zm1.62,16.329,0.76-.658,7,8-0.76.658ZM1316,695h1V802h-1V695ZM625.508,558.912l0.984,0.176-14,78-0.984-.176ZM612,637v-1h54v1H612Zm54.492-.089-0.984.178-14-77,0.984-.178ZM652,559v1H626v-1h26Z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: There aren't that many commands in an svg path. M for move, V is vertical line, H is horizontal line, L for a line, curves are a bit trickier with C, S, Q, and T, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths but manually combining these lines would take a lot of tinkering. Set it up as one long continuous path in your photoshop file.

Answer (score 0):

Your path is not a line. If in your code you remove `fill-opacity: 0; stroke: black;` you will still see the path filled black. The easiest solution to your problem is to use the path as a clipping path for an extremely wide line.

```css
 svg {
  max-width: 95%;
  max-height: 95%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
    border:1px solid;
}
line {
stroke-dasharray:1230px;
stroke-dashoffset:1230px;
  animation: draw 10s infinite linear;
}
@keyframes draw {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="60 150 1300 700">
   <line id="KK" x1="90" y1="500" x2="1320" y2="500" stroke="red" stroke-width = "700" clip-path="url(#clip)"/>
  <clipPath id="clip">
  <path class="cls-1" d="M97,801H96V744h1v57Zm-0.6-56.7L95.6,743.7l10-13,0.792,0.61ZM106,731h-1V721h1v10Zm-0.422,1.268,0.844-.536,7,11-0.844.536ZM112,743h1v6h-1v-6Zm0.61,6.312,0.78-.624,4,5-0.78.624ZM117,754v-1h8v1h-8Zm8,0h-1V705h1v49Zm0.481-48.865-0.962-.27,7-25,0.962,0.27ZM132,680h-1V660h1v20Zm-1.568-20.252-0.864.5-7-12,0.864-.5Zm-7.062-11.412-0.74-.672,10-11,0.74,0.672ZM133,637h-1V583h1v54Zm-1.588-53.717-0.824-.566,11-16,0.824,0.566Zm10.214-15.951,0.748-.664,8,9-0.748.664ZM150,576v-1h32v1H150Zm31.664-.63,0.672-.74,11,10-0.672.74ZM192,585h1v56h-1V585Zm2,56v-1h27v1H194Zm12-1h-1V601h1v39Zm15,1h-1V585h1v56Zm-0.646-55.646-0.708-.708,9-9,0.708,0.708ZM230,576v-1h32v1H230Zm32.354-.646-0.708-.708,7-7,0.708,0.708Zm6.292-8,0.708-.708,10,10-0.708.708ZM278,576h1v60h-1V576Zm-0.369,60.338,0.738-.676,11,12-0.738.676ZM288.6,647.706l0.808,0.588-8,11-0.808-.588ZM280.5,659.055l0.994-.11,4,36-0.994.11Zm4.027,36.116,0.94-.342,4,11-0.94.342ZM288,706h1v48h-1V706Zm1.487,0.112-0.974-.224,3-13,0.974,0.224ZM292,693h-1V666h1v27Zm0.217-26.549-0.434-.9,27-13,0.434,0.9Zm26.62-12.978,0.326-.946,32,11-0.326.946ZM350,664h1v51h-1V664Zm1,51v-1h11v1H351Zm11,0h-1V629h1v86Zm-0.929-85.5-0.142-.99,7-1,0.142,0.99Zm6.619-1.1,0.62-.784,19,15-0.62.784ZM386,643h1v49h-1V643Zm1,49v-1h7v1h-7Zm6.743,0.429,0.514-.858,10,6-0.514.858ZM403,698h1v35h-1V698Zm1.7,35.4,0.6-.8,8,6-0.6.8Zm8,6,0.6-.8,4,3-0.6.8ZM418,742h1v13h-1V742Zm1,1h-1V674h1v69Zm0.354-68.646-0.708-.708,4-4,0.708,0.708ZM423,670v-1H535v1H423Zm111.688-.61,0.624-.78,5,4-0.624.78Zm4.9,3.319,0.814,0.582-5,7-0.814-.582Zm-4.973,7.616,0.76-.65,6,7-0.76.65Zm5.946,6.427,0.868,0.5-4,7-0.868-.5ZM536,694h1v22h-1V694Zm0.366,15.34-0.732-.68,13-14,0.732,0.68Zm13.087-14.129-0.906-.422,14-30,0.906,0.422ZM563,665h-1V640h1v25Zm-1-25v-1h11v1H562Zm11.312-1.61-0.624-.78,5-4,0.624,0.78Zm5.168-4.249-0.96-.282,23-78,0.96,0.282ZM601,556h-1V543h1v13Zm0.39-13.312-0.78.624-8-10,0.78-.624Zm-8.113-9.272-0.554-.832,15-10,0.554,0.832Zm15.22-10.358-0.994-.116,7-60,0.994,0.116Zm7-60.016-1-.084,4-47,1,0.084Zm4-47.016-1-.052,3-57,1,0.052Zm3-56.994-1-.064,4-63,1,0.064Zm4-62.994-1-.076,4-53,1,0.076Zm3.908-53.329-0.814.582-5-7,0.814-.582Zm-4.933-6.867-0.948.316-3-9,0.948-.316ZM622,227h-1V217h1v10Zm0.5-9.95-1-.1,1-10,1,0.1Zm0.962-9.853-0.92-.394,3-7,0.92,0.394Zm2.947-6.906-0.814-.582,5-7,0.814,0.582Zm4.947-6.937-0.708-.708,7-7,0.708,0.708Zm7-7-0.708-.708,2-2,0.708,0.708ZM640,184h-1V167h1v17Zm0.671,0.376,0.658-.752,8,7-0.658.752Zm7.9,6.889,0.848-.53,5,8-0.848.53Zm4.956,7.911,0.936-.352,3,8-0.936.352Zm2.97,7.869,1-.09,1,11-1,.09Zm1,10.893,0.992,0.124-1,8-0.992-.124Zm-0.978,7.9,0.948,0.316-3,9-0.948-.316ZM653.54,234.8l0.92,0.394-3,7-0.92-.394Zm-4.039,8.229,1-.064,5,77-1,.064Zm5,76.995,1-.054,4,73-1,.054Zm4,73.009,1-.072,2,28-1,.072Zm2,28.008,1-.088,6,68-1,.088Zm6,68.038,0.986-.164,5,30-0.986.164Zm5.168,30.3,0.65-.76,14,12-0.65.76Zm13.878,11.844,0.894-.448,1,2-0.894.448Zm1.073,1.444,0.748,0.664-8,9-0.748-.664ZM678,542h1v11h-1V542Zm0.518,11.133,0.964-.266,21,76-0.964.266Zm21.072,76.154,0.82-.574,7,10-0.82.574ZM707,639v-1h9v1h-9Zm8,0h1v26h-1V639Zm-0.436,27.244,0.872-.488,42,75-0.872.488ZM725.5,761.95l-1,.1-1-10,1-.1Zm-1.013-10.071-0.97.242-2-8,0.97-.242Zm-2.038-8.1-0.894.448-4-8,0.894-.448Zm-4.023-8.041-0.848.53-5-8,0.848-.53Zm-5.008-8.012-0.832.554-6-9,0.832-.554Zm-6.062-9.077-0.708.708-8-8,0.708-.708ZM699.3,710.6l-0.6.8-8-6,0.6-.8Zm-8.032-6.022-0.536.844-11-7,0.536-.844Zm-11.044-7.025-0.448.894-10-5,0.448-.894Zm-10.066-5.027-0.316.948-12-4,0.316-.948ZM658.045,688.5l-0.09,1-11-1,0.09-1ZM647,687v1H634v-1h13Zm-13.071.5,0.142,0.99-14,2-0.142-.99Zm-14.087,2.021,0.316,0.948-12,4-0.316-.948Zm-12.066,4.027,0.448,0.894-10,5-0.448-.894Zm-10.019,5.01,0.486,0.874-9,5-0.486-.874Zm-9.091,5.065,0.668,0.744-10,9-0.668-.744Zm-10.02,9.018,0.708,0.708-9,9-0.708-.708Zm-9.056,9.067,0.82,0.574-7,10-0.82-.574Zm-7.037,10.063,0.894,0.448-5,10-0.894-.448Zm-5.038,10.1,0.97,0.242-3,12-0.97-.242ZM554.5,753.955l1,0.09-1,11-1-.09ZM553.6,765.3l0.8-.6,3,4-0.8.6ZM557,769v-1h12v1H557Zm12-1h-1V753h1v15Zm1-15v-1h21v1H570Zm21.354,0.354-0.708-.708,6-6,0.708,0.708ZM597,747h-1V734h1v13Zm0.3-12.6-0.6-.8,8-6,0.6,0.8Zm7.733-5.9-0.066-1,15-1,0.066,1ZM619,727h1v41h-1V727Zm0.68,41.384,0.64-.768,6,5-0.64.768Zm6.674,4.97-0.708-.708,4-4,0.708,0.708ZM630,768h-1V716h1v52Zm0.291-51.593-0.582-.814,7-5,0.582,0.814ZM637,711v-1h25v1H637Zm24.646-.646,0.708-.708,5,5-0.708.708ZM666,715h1v46h-1V715Zm1,46v-1h58v1H667Zm90-20h-1V716h1v25Zm0.307-24.605-0.614-.79,9-7,0.614,0.79ZM766,709v-1h26v1H766Zm26-1h-1V642h1v66Zm-0.743-65.571-0.514-.858,10-6,0.514,0.858ZM801,636v-1h13v1H801Zm12.68,0.384,0.64-.768,6,5-0.64.768Zm6.632,5.006-0.624-.78,5-4,0.624,0.78ZM825,637h-1V485h1V637Zm-0.571-150.743-0.858-.514,6-10,0.858,0.514ZM830,476h-1V465h1v11Zm0.354-10.646-0.708-.708,14-14,0.708,0.708ZM843,449h1v29h-1V449Zm-0.354,29.354,0.708-.708,6,6-0.708.708ZM850,484v-1h44v1H850Zm43,1h1V694h-1V485Zm0.752,209.434,0.5-.868,7,4-0.5.868ZM901,698v-1h10v1H901Zm10.457,0.2-0.914-.406,4-9,0.914,0.406ZM915,689v-1h4v1h-4Zm3,0h1v19h-1V689Zm2,19v-1h3v1h-3Zm3.39,0.312-0.78-.624,4-5,0.78,0.624ZM927,703h-1V691h1v12Zm0.354-11.646-0.708-.708,6-6,0.708,0.708ZM933,685h-1V671h1v14Zm0.4-13.7-0.8-.6,21-28,0.8,0.6ZM954,643h-1V622h1v21Zm0.468-20.824-0.936-.352,6-16,0.936,0.352Zm5.1-15.928,0.868-.5,8,14-0.868.5ZM967,620h1v22h-1V620Zm0.607,22.309,0.786-.618,11,14-0.786.618ZM979,656v-1h3v1h-3Zm3.5,0.028-1-.056,1-18,1,0.056Zm0.992-17.936-0.982-.184,3-16,0.982,0.184Zm3-15.977-0.974-.23,4-17,0.974,0.23Zm3.966-16.9-0.906-.422,7-15,0.906,0.422ZM997.4,590.3l-0.8-.6,9-12,0.8,0.6Zm8.97-11.962-0.74-.676,11-12,0.74,0.676Zm11-12-0.74-.668,9-10,0.74,0.668ZM1026,557h-1V517h1v40Zm0.42-39.73-0.84-.54,9-14,0.84,0.54Zm8.17-13.979,0.82-.582,10,14-0.82.582ZM1044,517h1v39h-1V517Zm0.63,39.335,0.74-.67,19,21-0.74.67Zm18.94,20.927,0.86-.524,8,13-0.86.524Zm7.97,12.924,0.92-.372,6,15-0.92.372Zm5.98,14.955,0.96-.282,5,17-0.96.282Zm4.99,16.951,0.98-.184,3,16-0.98.184ZM1085,638h1v11h-1V638Zm0.65,13.354,0.7-.708,4,4-0.7.708Zm4.7,4-0.7-.708,13-13,0.7,0.708ZM1103,642h-1V613h1v29Zm0.39-28.688-0.78-.624,4-5,0.78,0.624Zm3.26-4.958,0.7-.708,5,5-0.7.708ZM1111,615h1v15h-1V615Zm0.65,15.354,0.7-.708,4,4-0.7.708ZM1116,634h1v10h-1V634Zm0.61,10.31,0.78-.62,15,19-0.78.62Zm14.91,18.823,0.96-.266,8,29-0.96.266Zm7.98,28.9,1-.072,1,14-1,.072Zm1.17,14.338,0.66-.748,9,8-0.66.748ZM1150,714v-1h9v1h-9Zm8.61,0.312,0.78-.624,4,5-0.78.624ZM1162,719h1v25h-1V719Zm1.35,25.354-0.7-.708,11-11,0.7,0.708ZM1174,733h-1V711h1v22Zm0.05-21.5-0.1-1,10-1,0.1,1Zm9.6-1.144,0.7-.708,11,11-0.7.708ZM1195,721h-1V660h1v61Zm-0.67-60.622-0.66-.756,22-19,0.66,0.756ZM1216,641v-1h10v1h-10Zm9.65,0.354,0.7-.708,4,4-0.7.708ZM1230,645v-1h22v1h-22Zm21,0h1v95h-1V645Zm1,95v-1h12v1h-12Zm12-1h-1v-9h1v9Zm0.35-8.646-0.7-.708,9-9,0.7,0.708ZM1274,721h-1V687h1v34Zm0-34v-1h21v1h-21Zm21.35,0.354-0.7-.708,14-14,0.7,0.708ZM1308,671h1v16h-1V671Zm1.62,16.329,0.76-.658,7,8-0.76.658ZM1316,695h1V802h-1V695ZM625.508,558.912l0.984,0.176-14,78-0.984-.176ZM612,637v-1h54v1H612Zm54.492-.089-0.984.178-14-77,0.984-.178ZM652,559v1H626v-1h26Z"/>
</clipPath>  

</svg>
```